# 400 Bad Request Request Header Or Cookie Too Large - Rails with facebook and subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, cookies, nginx, subdomain

I have created application using subdomains in rails 4. It uses Turbolinks. I added a facebook plugin to it. On production, when I refresh the page, everything is ok. However, when I get on the link which uses subdomain, server responds with 400 status code.

**400 Bad Request**
Request Header Or Cookie Too Large
nginx/1.6.2

As you can see, I use nginx as webserver.

I tried to debug it and noticed, that on my subdomain facebook plugin generates two additional cookies.

[image: additional cookies generated by fb script]

When I'll delete those cookies, I can surf on my subdomain freely until I'll go back to root domain. After that, when I'll try to visit my subdomain again, those two cookies are generated again, and whole problem appears once again.

Does anybody know, why this is created and how to prevent facebook of generating it?

It doesn't appears on localhost. I wonder if this is nginx configuration?

My current FB integrations is provided using coffescript.

```
fb_root = null
fb_events_bound = false

fb_init =  ->
  loadFacebookSDK()
  bindFacebookEvents() unless fb_events_bound

bindFacebookEvents = ->
  $(document)
    .on('page:fetch', saveFacebookRoot)
    .on('page:change', restoreFacebookRoot)
    .on('page:load', ->
      FB?.XFBML.parse()
    )
  fb_events_bound = true

saveFacebookRoot = ->
  fb_root = $('#fb-root').detach()

restoreFacebookRoot = ->
  if $('#fb-root').length > 0
    $('#fb-root').replaceWith fb_root
  else
    $('body').append fb_root

loadFacebookSDK = ->
  window.fbAsyncInit = initializeFacebookSDK
  $.getScript("//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/all.js#xfbml=1")

initializeFacebookSDK = ->
  FB.init
  appId     : 'my_app_id'
  channelUrl: '//https://facebook.com/my_site
  status    : true
  cookie    : true
  xfbml     : true

@Facebook = { fb_init }

$(document).on "ready page:load pageshow", ->
  Facebook.fb_init()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in the coffee_script code.

I solved it by copying code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

to the html file right after body tag. This ensured to re-init facebook plugin even if turbolinks where implemented.

Here is the code:

```
body
  #fb-root
  javascript:
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY_APP_ID&version=v2.0";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```